# jquery validator onfocusout not working for checkbox and radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

Using jquery validator. validation is not performed when using tab to navigate the form.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2HUu/1/)

```
$(function () {
         var validator = $("#myForm").validate({ 
             onfocusout: function(element) {
                   this.element(element);
                },
             rules: { 
                 fname: "required", 
                 check: "required",
                 color: "required"
                }, 
             messages: { 
                 fname: "Enter your firstname", 
                 check: "you know you do",
                 color: "pick one!",
             }, 
         }); 
     });
```

I tried to perform a on blur on the checkbox. However, the event is trigger on form load. [Here's the improved fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2HUu/2/)

```
$('#check').on('blur', function() {
            $("#myForm").validate().element( this );
        }).blur();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution/work around the onfocusout issue is to use the on blur for both checkbox and radio.

```
$(function () {
    var validator = $("#myForm").validate({ 
        onfocusout: function(element) {
            this.element(element);
    },
    rules: { 
        fname: "required", 
        check: "required",
        radio: "required",
        color: "required"
    }, 
    messages: { 
        fname: "Enter your firstname", 
        check: "check your checkbox",
        radio: "check your radio",
        color: "pick one!",
    }, 
    }); 

    $('#check').on('blur', function() {
        $("#myForm").validate().element( this );
    });
    $('#radio').on('blur', function() {
        $("#myForm").validate().element( this );
    });
});
```

Take note that you do not call the blur function like this:

```
$('#check').on('blur', function() {
    $("#myForm").validate().element( this );
}).blur();
```

the initial blur function will cause the validation to be trigger on load

Here's the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2HUu/10/)

Answer (score 2):

onfocusout does not show error message, otherwise the best way to validate elements on blur is;

```
onfocusout: function(element) { 
    if( $(element).attr('name') ) { 
            this.element(element);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the onfocusout option.

```
"Validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. If nothing is entered, all rules are skipped, except when the field was already marked as invalid."
```

[Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Comment: Validation work on submit, only onfocusout does not work for checkbox or radio. Please see updated question for on blur

Comment: I think this is what I am trying to say for "ONFOCUSOUT" option