# Jquery validator valid status with ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to post a form using ajax after a form has been validated. However the .valid seems to be wrong.

Multiple action type is desired based on button.

This example is also not showing the errors messages correctly upon submit

```
$('#submit').click( function(){
        alert(validator.valid());
    });

$('#submit2').click( function(){
        alert(validator.valid());
        //do something else
    });
```

status become true if i enter a required field (e.g name)

[this is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2HUu/5/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quote OP:

> "I am trying to post a form using ajax after a form has been validated"

[As per documentation](http://validation.bassistance.de/validate/), your `ajax` goes inside the `submitHandler` callback function.

> **submitHandler** (default: native form submit)
>  **Type: Function()**
> Callback
>   for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form
>   as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right place to
>   submit a form via Ajax after it validated.

Using this callback, the click is captured automatically and the function is only fired on a valid form.

```
$(function () {

    var validator = $("#myForm").validate({
        // rules and options,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // your ajax goes here
            alert("valid form");
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/fXDwd/**

---

Quote OP:

> "However the `.valid` seems to be wrong."

**EDIT**

As per OP's comments and updated jsFiddle:

If you want to have multiple submit buttons do different things on one form, construct `click` handlers for each button which you've already done.  Now you must move those buttons to *outside* of the `<form></form>` container.  Otherwise, the plugin will treat them both as normal `submit` buttons and interfere with your click handlers.

The other problem is your implementation of [`.valid()`](http://validation.bassistance.de/valid/).  Attach it to the `form` element, `$("#myForm")`, not the validator initialization object.

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
    ...
</form>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit form" />
<input type="button" id="submit2" value="Submit form2" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(function () {
    var validator = $("#myForm").validate({
        // rules and options
    });

    $('#submit').click(function () {
        alert($("#myForm").valid());
        //do something
    });

    $('#submit2').click(function () {
        alert($("#myForm").valid());
        //do something else
    });
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/vfrGU/**

Comment: on an invalid form. The error messages for all invalid field is not shown on clicking submit. It is only triggered when pressing enter on name field. Tab navigation will not trigger checkbox and radio as well

Comment: What if there are multiple button for different action on the same form?

Comment: @user1549804, you'll need to show enough code to demonstrate the actual true issue.  Your OP says nothing about multiple buttons or error messages not being shown.

Comment: Sorry i am new to this. I have edited the fiddle and question to include the protion on multiple button and error messages

Comment: This answer has been accepted. Some credit have to be given to @ankush-jain as he is the first to give the same answer. This solution will be complete if my other question on [onfocusout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810107/jquery-validator-onfocusout-not-working-for-checkbox-and-radio) is address as well.

Comment: @user1549804, the `onfocusout` trigger is only active after the form fails the first time.  Using my last jsFiddle, explain exactly how you want it different.

Comment: As mentioned, using the latest. You will notice that if you use tab to navigate the form text & dropdown validation will be triggered and error displayed. However, checkbox and radio will not have any event. Errors for all fields will only be displayed on form submit. [A incorrect workaround implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/r2HUu/2/) can be done but onblur is trigger on form load. The desired solution will be the ability to validate each  element as the entry is being done and also after submit to capture all remaining errors

Answer (score 0):

try this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/r2HUu/4/

It's working. I just checked form' validation by `$("#myForm").valid()`

Comment: will you be able to comment on this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810107/jquery-validator-onfocusout-not-working-for-checkbox-and-radio] as well? It's regards to onfocusout

Comment: @sparky answer is accepted though this is the first response. It gives a more detail answer.